# Detener script Python en robot NAO al tocar la cabeza

Tags: python, python-2.7

Mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo un script en Python que se ejecuta para que el robot NAO realice diversas acciones sin parar hasta que se detenga la ejecución, sin embargo por razones de seguridad (en caso de que el robot se vuelva loco *y nos quiera matar a todos*) requiero de añadir alguna instrucción para detenerlo usando el sensor táctil de su cabeza en caso de que este sea presionado.

Leí un poco sobre el modulo ALTouch con el que se puede generar el modulo TouchChanged() pero este actúa sobre todos los sensores y no solo sobre el sensor táctil en la cabeza.

Alguna idea o documentación relacionada sera bienvenida.

Comment: Luis, bienvenido a SOes. Tu pregunta me parece muy interesante, y a la vez, es la primera pregunta que existe aqui en SOes de NAO (yo personalmente nunca habia escuchado de tal robot) Espero de verdad que puedas obtener tu respuesta en tu idioma nativo, pero si es complicado, quizas puedas preguntar en [so]. Tambien nunca esta demas echarle un vistazo al articulo: [ask] para mejorar en todo lo posible tu pregunta. Saludos! (estare pendiente de tu pregunta porque soy fan de Python hehehe)

Comment: Hola @LuisHongo, bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), ante todo deberías abordar mejor tu problema, en lo particular nunca he escuchado sobre NAO. Usas alguna otra librería? Comenta que librerias usas y se un poco mas explicito y asi podremos ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la cálida bienvenida @ReinierHernándezÁvila , estoy usando específicamente Motion (movimiento del robot), Almath (utilizar librerías de Choreographe), Numpy (cálculos de señal RMS del microfono frontal), Matplotlib (elaborar diagramas de las señales obtenidas) y Random (movimiento aleatorios en base a tiempo y aperturas), mi proyecto consiste en hacer bailar al robot de acuerdo a los que escucha mediante el micrófono frontal.

Cualquier duda siéntase libre de preguntar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Gracias @Kenny yo no conocía nada de Python hasta hace muy poco que me encontré con este robot y comencé a trabajar con el, voy a tomar en cuenta tu consejo y preguntare en Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como indicas el modulo ALTouch genera el evento TouchChanged() donde sea que el robot es tocado, sin embargo TouchChanged() provee una lista de la parte del cuerpo y un booleano con el estado del estimulo.

Por ejemplo:

```
[[“Head/Touch/Middle”, True], [“ChestBoard/Button”, True]]
[[“Head/Touch/Middle”, False]]
[[“LArm”, True], [“RHand”, False]]
```

Ref: [Documentación de Softbank Robotics](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/sensors/altouch.html) para el modulo ALTouch, incluye ejemplo de uso en su sitio web.

Answer (score 0):

Perfecto ya descubri como hacerlo despues de varias pruebas con el script de ejemplo, fue tan sencillo como cambiar una palabra

```
global memory
    memory = ALProxy("ALMemory")
    memory.subscribeToEvent("MiddleTactilTouched",
        "ReactToTouch",
        "onTouched")
```

El ejemplo de [Aldebaran](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/sensors/altouch.html#how-it-works) usa TouchChanged que engloba todos los miembros del robot y sensores en lugar de MiddleTactilTouched que solo trabaja sobre el sensor medio de la cabeza.

Muchas gracias a aquellos que se tomaron un poco de su tiempo para responder mi pregunta.